# The ™ symbol in my application is not allowing me to launch the application using pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, ui-automation, pywinauto

I have tried multiple ways to launch my application. In some cases, I am a able to launch it but unable to use the print_control_identifier or in another case, I just am not able to even launch my application. I tried this piece of code shown in pywinauto 0.6.2 getting started document.

```
# coding: utf-8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from subprocess import Popen
from pywinauto import Desktop
Popen('TRACE™ 3D Plus.exe', shell=True)
dlg = Desktop(backend="uia").TRACE™ 3D Plus
dlg.wait('visible')
```

Now, when I run this piece of code from the command prompt, I get the error,

```
File "3d.py", line 6
dlg = Desktop(backend="uia").TRACE\ufffd 3D Plus
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

As I see it, the ™ symbol in my application name is not being interpreted correctly while executing the piece of code.

Any thoughts on the same and what I can do to make it work ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sorry, too busy at the main job. Will take a look end of week.

Comment: BTW, `dlg = Desktop(backend="uia").TRACE\ufffd 3D Plus` should be `dlg = Desktop(backend="uia")['TRACE\ufffd 3D Plus']`

Comment: Have you tried `Popen('TRACE\ufffd 3D Plus.exe', shell=True)`?

Comment: You can also try `os.listdir('<path to target app folder>')` and see which names are listed in Python.

Comment: Hi Vasily, I tried the code as mentioned by you:                                 
    from subprocess import Popen
    from pywinauto import Desktop 
    Popen('TRACE™ 3D Plus.exe', shell=True)
    dlg = Desktop(backend="uia")['TRACE™ 3D Plus']      I ran this and in the command prompt got the message                                 
    'TRACET' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."  I then generally listed the files under my application folder to see the exe name and it displays it as ' 'TRACET 3D Plus.exe' in the command prompt.

Comment: It would be good for me to discuss it over a chat at end of week as you mentioned if thats ok for you.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Obvously you need to add double quotes! `Popen('"TRACE™ 3D Plus.exe"', shell=True)` Because Windows shell doesn't treat it as a monolit.

Comment: Tried with double quotes also. I get the same message                               ' "TRACET 3D Plus.exe" ' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Can you run this command from `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Hi Vasily, sorry for the late reply. But I am not able to to run it from cmd.exe . I get the same error

Comment: Do you run it with full path and double quotes included? `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Trane\TRACE 3D  Plus\TRACE™ 3D Plus.exe"`

Comment: Running from cmd.exe , I navigated to trace 3d plus directory and then ran this command. Is that what you are asking ?

Comment: By this command I meant , Trace 3D plus.exe

Comment: I mean running `Trace 3D plus.exe` from any folder in `cmd.exe` (without changing work dir). What the full path is successful for you?

Comment: Vasily, thank you for your kind gesture. Will ping you on Skype and then proceed according to your convenient timing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we figured out by Skype, the following method works for this app:

```
import os
from pywinauto import Application

exe_folder = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Trane\\TRACE 3D Plus"
executable = os.path.join(exe_folder, "TRACE\u2122 3D Plus.exe")

os.chdir(exe_folder)
app = Application(backend="uia").start(executable)
```

It was really hard to run this executable even from `cmd.exe`. Also we had to change working directory to the folder where executable is. Otherwise it shows internal exception (seems like the app issue).

Comment: Hi Vasily, yes we were able to launch the application using the code:            from pywinauto import application
    app = Application.
    import os
    os.chdir(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Trane\TRACE 3D Plus")
    import subprocess                                      subprocess.Popen('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Trane\\TRACE 3D Plus\\TRACE\u2122 3D Plus.exe"',shell=True).

Comment: But since we did not use app.start or app.connect, I get a name error when I use "dlg = Desktop(backend="uia").Calculator
dlg.window(auto_id='num8Button', control_type='Button')" as mentioned in the guide, So how can I specify my application window name and control type of the button I want to click on ?